# Put the <ol><li> tags between <h1></h1> tag?

Tags: html, html-heading

Can I place list tag elements between "h1" heading tags, or are there some kind of rules saying this is invalid?

I have never seen anyone put "ol" and "li" between `<h1></h1>` tags, but I am not sure the reason. Is it because it is bad for SEO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

h1 is a block element and will only accept inline children (span, img, etc).

ol is a block element, and it would be simply wrong to put it inside a heading element as it is not semantically viable, since it is probably incorrect to assume that a list can be a title of a page.

All this would make your SEO not working.

A bit more info here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp and there stackoverflow.com/questions/4041820/are-h1-h2-h3-h4-tags-block-or-inline-elements#answer-4041841

Answer (score 1):

All HTML specifications forbid `ul` inside `h1`, see e.g. [HTML 4.01 on `h1`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/global.html#edef-H1) (where the content model notation `%inline;` means text and text-level markup; this excludes list elements for example).

However, you *can* use `ul` inside `h1` in the sense that browsers parse it and construct a document tree where `ul` is a child of `h1`. You can see this visually by testing what happens if you e.g. set a background color on the heading element:

```html
<style>
h1 { background: yellow }
</style>
<h1>Hello<ul><li>item</ul>world</h1>
```

So the `h1` element embraces the list and continues after it. This is different from what happens if you try to nest, say, `ul` inside `p`. (The `<ul>` tag implicitly closes the `p` element.)

Whether you *should* do so is a different matter. It is difficult to imagine a situation where a heading meaningfully contains a bulleted list. The heading elements in HTML are meant to be heading texts, as opposite to headers (which may contains headings). And a `ul` inside a `h1` could confuse a speech browser, for example, since they might be not prepared to deal with such constructs.

Regarding SEO, we really do not know how search engines internally work and how they would handle such an odd construct. You could always test it with some engines. And of course they might change this tomorrow, especially if they notice that people are trying to fool them with some odd (and invalid) HTML. Besides, the apparently popular idea of improving your status in SEO by using `h1` for important content is based on misunderstanding. To the extent that search engines pay attention to `h1` markup at all, they most probably take it as relative importance *within the page*. So you would just be saying that everything else on the page is less important than the content of this element.

Answer (score -1):

You need to place the heading tags *inside* of the list item tags. For example:

```
<ul>
   <li><h1>Headers</h1></li>
   <li><h2>Unordered</h2></li>
   <li><h3>List</h3></li>
</ul>
```

OR

```
<ol>
   <li><h1>Headers</h1></li>
   <li><h2>Ordered</h2></li>
   <li><h3>List</h3></li>
</ol>
```

Thereafter, use CSS to aptly style your H1, H2 & H3 tags as per your requirement or page styling. This is an effective way of optimising content in lists or even tables...